# SystemVerilog parameters for an or function

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I have written the following working code to calculate an enable signal.

```
logic            l_en [0:N-1];
logic    [0:N-1] l_output_grant [0:M-1];

always_comb begin
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) begin
    l_en[i]   = |{l_output_grant[0][i], 
                  l_output_grant[1][i], 
                  l_output_grant[2][i], 
                  l_output_grant[3][i], 
                  l_output_grant[4][i]};
  end
end
```

I am now trying to change the code to parameter the [0] through [4].  I tried the following code

```
logic            l_en [0:N-1];
logic    [0:N-1] l_output_grant [0:M-1];

always_comb begin
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) begin
    for(int j=0; j<M; j++) begin
      l_en[i]   = |l_output_grant[j][i]; 
    end
  end
end
```

Which doesn't work.  I assume this is because it recalculates with each iteration of j and thus clears the enable assigned by [j][i] if [j+1][i] is low.

What other ways could I do this please?

Comment: Are l_en and l_output_grant also parametrized to N and M? or are their declarations independent? Please show their declarations.

Comment: Yes they are.  I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l_en[i] = |l_output_grant[j][i]` overrides the previews assignment. Also, `|l_output_grant[j][i]` is a bit-wise or operator to a signal bit, which does nothing.

For the desired functionality use the `|=` bit-wise operator; `l_en |= l_output_grant[j]`. Alternatively, use the traditional Verilog method `l_en = l_en | l_output_grant[j]`. Remember to clear the old values by assign `l_en` to all zeros before the for-loops. Failing to clear the values will create latches and prevent any high to low transition from ever happening. Since the widths match the `for(i=...)` loop is not needed.

```
always_comb begin
  l_en = '0; // all bits to zero
  for(int j=0; j<M; j++) begin
    l_en |= l_output_grant[j];
    // equivalent to: l_en[0:N-1] = l_en[0:N-1] | l_output_grant[j][0:N-1];
  end
end
```

Note: Use the Verilog style if the synthesizers does not support `|=` operator. The simulator will support the operator if SystemVerilog is supported.

Comment: Thanks, although at a glance, I don't think that code takes in the transposition.  My intention is that I have N enable signals, and that the i'th enable is high if the i'th bit of any of the M packed output grants are high.  I could be wrong though, i'll check tomorrow.  Thankyou.

Comment: It works, see example: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/379 . I had to remove some SV because of Icarus' limits. The key points work.

Comment: Cheers, I see what you did now, but unfortunately it won't work using the signal definitions I have, as l_en is not a packed number.

Comment: - But I am just going to pack all my signals throughout the design as I can't see any reason why not!